# expression language, combined condition in if then else

Tags: java, xpages, el

I want to declare a combined condition for an if then else statement with expression language.

Unfortunately my code fails.

```
((compositeData.data.phone eq null) and (compositeData.data.mail eq null) and (compositeData.data.linkP eq null)) ? false : true
```

Comment: The code doesn't fail, it does what you have written. However, you have failed to describe what *you think* that the code does, and this might be something else.

Comment: Have you tried *empty* instead of *null*?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your code should work. I have tested it without any problems.

Take a look at the following code snippets...

**Custom Control:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    SHOW PHONE: 
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{compositeData.data.phone}"></xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    SHOW MAIL:
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{compositeData.data.mail}"></xp:text>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="SIMPLE TEXT" style="color:rgb(255,0,0);font-size:24pt"
        rendered="#{((compositeData.data.phone eq null) and (compositeData.data.mail eq null)) ? false : true}">
    </xp:text>

</xp:view>
```

---

**XPAGE (first scenario setting compositeData.mail):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xc:customControl>
        <xc:this.data>
            <xc:data mail="test@testmail.com"></xc:data>
        </xc:this.data>
    </xc:customControl>

</xp:view>
```

*Expected result:*

[image]

---

**XPAGE (second scenario without setting compositeData.mail):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xc:customControl>
    </xc:customControl>

</xp:view>
```

*Expected result:*

[image]

**Hint:** I have done my tests with a `Domino 8.5.3FP6` and a `Domino 9.0.1FP4` server. As I have mentioned above, without any troubles.